# Why views retrieves results one by one

Tags: views

I'm actually trying get the count of total rows retrieved by view. When I added `count($row)` in `Global:PHP` of views field it returned `1`. That also ten times, Means query executed 10 times to retrieve 10 row of data. When I printed the query with `dpq($view->build_info['query']);` it returned same query 10 times. How can I avoid multiple execution of same query.

Comment: It executes the query only once, but renders each row individually. If the query returned 10 results, that means 10 rows to render.

Comment: @AyeshK Then how can I get the count before rendering rows

Answer (score 0):

You can list the number of results instead with a snippet of php code in the header:

```
<?php
  $view = views_get_current_view();
  print $view->total_rows; 
?>
```

Learned this trick from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989197

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it by taking the number of records in the view.
For that you can use the **Global: Result summary** in that you have @total -- the total records in the set.
You can use this. I don't know whether this answer meets your need.
Just give a try:)